# Removing specific indexed object from ArrayList and removing it from the background

Tags: java, javafx, game-development

I'm trying to implement a life counter within my game and having some issues. The lives are represented by an image, so when the player loses a life, one image is removed. I've managed to do this but it's done in an inefficient way (chained if statements etc) and i'm looking for a way to do it better. I added in an ArrayList instead, and then when the player dies, a life is lost (and image removed) at a certain index, and i've implemented it but I think i've gone wrong somewhere as i'm getting a "Index out of bounds for length 0" exception. This is the relevenant code i've got:

Creates 5 life objects & adds them in to the background

```java
background.addLife(new Lives("file:resources/frogLife.png", 30, 5, 5));
background.addLife(new Lives("file:resources/frogLife.png", 30, 40, 5));
background.addLife(new Lives("file:resources/frogLife.png", 30, 75, 5));
background.addLife(new Lives("file:resources/frogLife.png", 30, 110, 5));
background.addLife(new Lives("file:resources/frogLife.png", 30, 145, 5));
```

The below runs on a timer, if animal dies, it's supposed to get the index of right most Lives image object, remove it from the background, remove from the ArrayList and decrement number of lives.

```
else if (animal.getDeathStatus() == true)
{
  life = life.getLifeFromIndex(numOfLives);
  background.removeLife(life);
  life.removeLife(numOfLives);
  numOfLives--;
}
```

The lives class, when object of this type is created, it should be added to the ArrayList

```
public void Lives extends ImageView
{
    ArrayList<Lives> Lives = new ArrayList<Lives>();

    public Lives(String imageLink, int size, int xpos, int ypos)
    {
        setImage(new Image(imageLink, size,size, true, true));
        setX(xpos);
        setY(ypos);
        Lives.add(this);
    }

    public Lives getLifeFromIndex(int index)
    {
        return Lives.get(index);
    }

    public void removeLife(int index)
    {
        Lives.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have done things differently. `Lives` to `Life`. Life.setImage. Then create the ArrayList in the main code. Then to remove a life `Life life = lives.get(lives.size() - 1); background.remove(life); lives.remove(life);` Something like that.

Comment: @Sedrick Wouldn't I need to add each element separately into the ArrayList though when creating them in this line ``background.addLife(new Lives("file:resources/frogLife.png", 30, 5, 5));`` ?

Comment: You've got 1 `Lives` list per `Lives` object. (Please use proper java naming conventions there btw and use variable names starting with a lowercase letter btw.) Removing any index other than  the one at index 0 will result in an exception as will calling the `removeLife` method for the same instance twice... Imho you should create a seperate class for managing the lives. Adding extra logic to an`ImageView` for this purpose seems unnecessary.Using a`HBox`you could also simply do`hbox.getChildren().remove(0);`for as long as there are children in the`HBox`.This would also take care of positioning

Comment: The way you add lives to the background is illogical and will lead to problems.

Comment: @Sedrick Why is that? It's not really different to having a counter instead, i'm just adding an image in place of a counter and each time a life is lost, an image gets removed from the screen. I've managed to do it using your first suggestion with the ``Life life = lives.get(lives.size() - 1);`` etc so thanks for that

Comment: You basically have four ArrayList. All with one element.

Comment: I meant five ArrayList.

Comment: I removed the code in the ``Life`` class about the ArrayList stuff, so now it's literally just a class to set the image & x/y of the object, then created a single array list within my Player class and then did all the object creation, adding it to a list in there instead within methods rather than within the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add .isEmpty() to check if there is anything to delete before actually delete it? This would prevent to running out of bounds of list.

Comment: Ok I've added that in, a method called ``checkIfEmpty`` in the ``Lives`` class and changed the Else if statement to this ``animal.getDeathStatus() == true && life.checkIfEmpty() == false`` so now it doesn't crash but it doesn't actually remove anything either